# Getting Data from a Web Service

Tags: wsdl, asmx

I did the following:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>wsdl.exe http://ws.strikeiron.com/CensusData?WSDL

This created a following file: CensusData.cs which was then added to my C# project.

I would like to see some data now so:

```
CensusData CD = new CensusData();
```

Looking at the inteli sense I figured out that I will probably need to use one of the methods named: `BeginGetEconomic_ForState` and here is where my C# skills are not good enough anymore.

After typing `CD.BeginGetEconomic_ForState("Utah",`  the intelisense shows AsyncCallback callbackm object asyncState)

What exactly should I do to get the data ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! WSDL.EXE is part of the ASMX technology. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Also, see "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)"

Comment: Also, why did you use `BeginGetEconomic_ForState`? Most likely, you want `GetEconomic_ForState`.